# Lunch Count Daily Save and Wipe Script

Tags: string, triggers, google-sheets

I work for a school system looking to have their lunch numbers for the day saved each night and then the numbers wiped. We have tried to find someone to write us a script with triggers but no one has been able to figure it out thus far. Any help would be highly appreciated. This is our last hope. https://docs.google.com/a/bradleyschools.org/spreadsheets/d/1KZ8LuABtUE1I4jFKVzroXKaJVOcD9LArewRl5wRFRbA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Check out this post and craft a question that is more likely to be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should post whatever you have tried till now and also your spreadsheet link is not accessible to public

Answer (score 0):

## Lunch Counter WebApp

I took a stab at the problem and here it is.  I have it working as a webapp contained in a spreadsheet and the lunchcount gets posted and reset every night around 10:00 PM.  Every time you do a get on the url it checks to see if the trigger is set and if it's not then it creates a new one. But it won't create more than one.  I checked it last night and the trigger is working fine. Don't forget to put in the SpreadSheetID for the postLunchCount and also run setupNightlyTrigger() once to get the trigger installed.  It run's by itself after that.

LunchCounter.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(displayCount)
      .getCount();

    });
    function incrementCount()
    {
      google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(displayCount)
          .lunchCounter();
    }
    function displayCount(n)
    {
      $('#cnt').text(n);
    }
    console.log('My Code');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="cnt"></div>
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Increment" onClick="incrementCount();" style="width:200px;height:200px;"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs

```
function onOpen()
{
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('My Tools')
      .addItem('Lunch Counter','lunchCounter')
      .addItem('Load SideBar', 'loadSideBar')
      .addItem('Reset Lunch Count','resetLunchCount')
      .addItem('Post Lunch','postLunchCount')
      .addToUi();
}

function lunchCounter()
{
  var prop=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var count=Number(prop.getProperty('LunchCount'));
  count++;
  prop.setProperty('LunchCount', count);
  return(count);
}

function getCount()
{
  var prop=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var count=Number(prop.getProperty('LunchCount'));
  return(count);
}

function resetLunchCount()
{
  postLunchCount();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('LunchCount', '0');
}

function postLunchCount()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadSheetID');
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('DailyLunchCount');
  var dt=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var cnt=getCount();
  var row=[dt,cnt];
  sht.appendRow(row);
}

function setupNightlyTrigger()
{
  if(!isTrigger('resetLunchCount'))
  {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('resetLunchCount').timeBased().atHour(22).everyDays(1).create();
  }
}

function loadSideBar()
{
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('LunchCounter');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function doGet()
{
  setupNightlyTrigger();
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('LunchCounter');
  html.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
  return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)

}

function isTrigger(handlerName)
{
  var r=false;
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  for (var i=0;i<triggers.length;i++) 
  {
    if (handlerName==triggers[i].getHandlerFunction()) 
    {
      r=true;
      break;
    }
  }
  return r;
}
```

This is what the webapp looks like on an Iphone:
It's really not that big.  I did it as a screen shot.  On my iphone the button size is about 3/4" and the lunch count is diplayed above it.  I'm don't really know what you wanted but I figured a single button is simple User Interface.

[image]

Spreadsheet Looks Like this:

[image]

Comment: It posted and reset tonight again.